# How can I add an href to a q-table (Quasar Data Table)?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have put a q-table in my page to show my data. this is work correctly. I want to put an href in first column and another in last column. You should can click on them to go to other pages for showing details row and edit row Respectively.

Title: go to page /#/offer/uuid

Edit: go to page /#/account/offers/edit/uuid

```
    <template>
      <q-page>
        <div class="row justify-center">
            <q-table
              :data="data"
              :columns="columns"
              row-key="id"
              selection="single"
              :selected.sync="selected"
              :filter="filter"
              :loading="loading"
            >
            </q-table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </q-page>
    </template>

<script>
.....
columns: [
        {
          name: 'title',
          required: true,
          label: 'Title',
          align: 'left',
          field: row => row.title,
          sortable: true,
          format: val => '<a href="/offer/">' + val + '</a>' //this is not work
        },
        {
          name: 'category',
          label: 'Category',
          field: 'category',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: 'payment',
          label: 'Payment',
          field: 'payment'
        },
        {
          name: 'action',
          label: 'Edit',
          field: 'key',
          format: val => '<a href="/account/offers/edit/">' + val + '</a>' //this is not work
        }
      ]
.....
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of Quasar are you using? I think the short answer to your question is that you need to use scoped slots instead of a `format` function.

Answer (score 9):

This answer assumes Quasar 1.0.0-rc4. For earlier versions it may look a bit different but the crux of it is that you need to use scoped slots.

There are scoped slots called `body-cell-[name]` that can be used to render content that isn't plain text. Here the `[name]` portion should match the `name` for the corresponding column in your `columns` definition.

```html
<q-table ...>
    <template v-slot:body-cell-title="cellProperties">
        <q-td :props="cellProperties">
            <a href="#/offer/">{{ cellProperties.value }}</a>
        </q-td>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:body-cell-action="cellProperties">
        <q-td :props="cellProperties">
            <a href="#/account/offers/edit/">{{ cellProperties.value }}</a>
        </q-td>
    </template>
</q-table>
```

My use of `v-slot` assumes Vue 2.6.0+, for earlier versions you would use `slot` and `slot-scope` instead.

You haven't explained where the UUID part of your URL comes from so I haven't included that in the code above. I would imagine it is included somewhere in the row data, so in practice you would need something like `:href="'#/offer/' + encodeURIComponent(cellProperties.row.uuid)"`.

If you're using a routing library such as Vue Router then there are alternatives to building URLs directly within `<a>` tags. You may wish to investigate further before sprinkling hand-crafted URLs throughout your application code. However, the use of scoped slots is likely to remain no matter how you implement your links.

Answer (score 3):

Use :href. For example:

```
<a :href="'/app/product/'+props.row.productId">{{ props.row.name }}</a>
```